# How to make dropdown as selected in edit mode in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

1. This is my page when I click on Edit the dropdown is not selected with value in the dropdown list ... [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLXw9.png)
2. In edit mode i got like this ... [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LrUJ.png)

   - Dropdown shown with values... [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wFhO.png)
3. I need like this ... [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I05ac.png)

Here is my angular code:

```
<select class="form-control form-control-sm form-control-Cutom-height" id="dropdown" style="height: 38px;" ng-model="suppliment.PurchaseTypeId">                                                                    
    <option ng-repeat="Supple in PTSupplement" ng-selected="{{ Supple.PurchaseTypeId == suppliment.PurchaseTypeId }}" value="{{Supple.PurchaseTypeId}}" >                                                                             
        {{Supple.PurchaseType}}                                                                                       
    </option>                                                                                   
</select>
```

Please help me :)

Comment: Please provide additional code

Answer (score 0):

It appears as if when you display the dropdown, the your value is not be populated as the selected value properly.   When using `<select>` in AngularJS, you can specify the `ng-options` attribute and use that to generate all of the `<option>` fields for you without doing the `ng-repeat` that you're doing.

From the [AngularJS docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected) regarding the use of `ngSelected`:

> Note: ngSelected does not interact with the select and ngModel directives, it only sets the selected attribute on the element. If you are using ngModel on the select, you should not use ngSelected on the options, as ngModel will set the select value and selected options.

Instead use the following:

```
<select 
    class="form-control form-control-sm form-control-Cutom-height" 
    id="dropdown" 
    style="height: 38px;" 
    ng-model="suppliment.PurchaseTypeId"
    ng-options="Supple.PurchaseTypeId as Supple.PurchaseType for Supple in PTSupplement">
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you Michael...Its working like as i am expected, thank you for your support..